# Custom Box Width Size Within Shiny

Tags: shiny

I am building a shiny app which is try to re-create some old reports I had, which I built from excel or data studio. To do this my desire is to use fluidrow and box within Shiny, but rather than have an integer width between 1 and 12 I'd like to be able to have a more custom width (eg 2.5), or an alternate way of achieving such custom widths.

Is this possible?!

Many thanks
Dylan

Comment: Can you please share the code you need to fix?

Comment: Hi @AlexSkorokhod, here is a segment of the ui part of the code (would this suffice): 
dashboardBody(tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "dig_web",
  fluidRow(column(width = 2, box(title = "Unique Visitors", textOutput("stat1")), box(title = "Return Visitors", textOutput("stat2"))
 ),column(width = 2, box(title = "Avg. Time on Site", textOutput("stat3")),box(title = "Bounce Rate", textOutput("stat4"))
 ),column(width = 4, box(width = 12, title = "Top Web Pages", plotOutput("plot1", height=200))
 ),column(width = 4, box(width = 12, title = "Top Wines", plotOutput("plot2", height=200))
 )) )) )

Comment: Sorry about the mess. You'll note here i'm simply using width = 2 or 4. But would love to be able to set it as 2.5 or 3.5 etc.